# Slick2D get image x and y

Tags: java, eclipse, image, slick2d

Ok, so i have a car that you can drive around in my game. It's basically an Image that drives around on a background, a and d turns it, w and s drives back and forth. But i want to make some borders on the screen edges so it doesnt just keep driving out into nothing, but to do that i think i have to get the x and y location of the Image. Does anyone know how to get this/know another way of making borders in Slick2D?

Thanks, Marco.

This is the GameplayState code:

```
package myprojects.main;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.Sound;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class GameplayState extends BasicGameState {

    int stateID = -1;
    Image imgBG = null;
    Image player = null;
    float scale = 1.0f;
    Sound ding = null;
    Sound gamemusic = null;
    int height;
    int width;
    private static int rightSide = 1200;
    private static int topSide = 800;
    float startGameScale = 1;
    float scaleStep = 0.001f;
    int[] duration = { 200, 200 };
    public Car car;
    // Animation car, driveUp, driveDown, driveRight, driveLeft;

    boolean hasWon;

    GameplayState(int stateID) {
        this.stateID = stateID;
    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return stateID;
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
            throws SlickException {
        imgBG = new Image("myprojects/main/resources/land.png");
        player = new Image("myprojects/main/resources/playercar.png");
        ding = new Sound("myprojects/main/resources/ding.wav");
        gamemusic = new Sound("myprojects/main/resources/gamemusic.wav");
        car = new Car(300,300);

        /**
         * Image[] carUp = {new Image("myprojects/main/resources/carUp.png"),
         * new Image("myprojects/main/resources/carUp.png")}; Image[] carDown =
         * {new Image("myprojects/main/resources/carDown.png"), new
         * Image("myprojects/main/resources/carDown.png")}; Image[] carRight =
         * {new Image("myprojects/main/resources/carRight.png"), new
         * Image("myprojects/main/resources/carRight.png")}; Image[] carLeft =
         * {new Image("myprojects/main/resources/carLeft.png"), new
         * Image("myprojects/main/resources/carLeft.png")};
         * 
         * driveUp = new Animation(carUp, duration, false); driveDown = new
         * Animation(carDown, duration, false); driveRight = new
         * Animation(carRight, duration, false); driveLeft = new
         * Animation(carLeft, duration, false); player = driveDown;
         **/

    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
            throws SlickException {
        imgBG.draw(0, 0);
        gc.setSoundVolume(0.05f);
        gamemusic.loop();
        g.drawString("Pause Game", 1100, 775);
        g.drawImage(car.getImage(), car.getX(), car.getY());

    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
            throws SlickException {
        Input input = gc.getInput();
        // Check if outside left border
        if(car.x < 0) {
            car.setX(0);
        }
        // Check if outside top border
        if(car.y < 0) {
            car.setY(0);
        }
        // Check if outside right border
        if(car.x >= gc.getWidth() - car.getWidth()) {
            car.setX(gc.getWidth() - car.getWidth());
        }
        // Check if outside bottom border
        if(car.y >= gc.getHeight() - car.getHeight()) {
            car.setY(gc.getHeight() - car.getHeight());
        }

        int mouseX = input.getMouseX();
        int mouseY = input.getMouseY();
        boolean hasWon = false;

        if ((mouseX <= rightSide && mouseX >= rightSide - 100)
                && (mouseY <= topSide && mouseY >= topSide - 50)) {
            hasWon = true;
        }
        if (hasWon) {
            if (input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)) {
                sbg.enterState(StarRacingGame.MAINMENUSTATE);
            } else {

            }
        }

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            ding.play();
            sbg.enterState(StarRacingGame.MAINMENUSTATE);
        }

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)) {
            car.rotate(-0.2f * delta);
        }

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)) {
            car.rotate(0.2f * delta);
        }

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S)) {
            float hip = 0.4f * delta;

            float rotation = car.getRotation();

            car.x -= hip * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));
            car.y += hip * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));

        }

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)) {
            if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LSHIFT)) {
                float hip = 1.4f * delta;
                float rotation = car.getRotation();

                car.x += hip * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));
                car.y -= hip * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
            } else {
                float hip = 0.4f * delta;
                float rotation = car.getRotation();

                car.x += hip * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));
                car.y -= hip * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Car code:

```
    package myprojects.main;

import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Car {
public int x;
public int y;
public Image image;

public Car(int x, int y) throws SlickException{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    image = new Image("myprojects/main/resources/playercar.png");

}

public org.newdawn.slick.Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return 100;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return 100;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;

}

public void rotate(float f) {
    image.rotate(f);
}

public float getRotation() {
    return image.getRotation();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a Car class that has an Image.  With this class, you can have ints that hold the x and y values representing the car's location, as well as the image of the car.  Then, you just set the values or x and y and rotate the image like you are doing in your example, except for the Car object.  You may do this already, I am not sure though without more code than just the input handler.  To draw it, do something like this in your render:

```
drawImage(car.getImage(), car.getX(), car.getY());
```

As far as borders, assuming you just don't want your Car to go off screen, you can do something like this:

```
// Check if outside left border
if(car.getX() < 0) {
    car.setX(0);
}
// Check if outside top border
if(car.getY() < 0) {
    car.setY(0);
}
// Check if outside right border
if(car.getX() >= SCREEN_WIDTH - car.getWidth()) {
    car.setX(SCREEN_WIDTH - car.getWidth());
}
// Check if outside bottom border
if(car.getY() >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - car.getHeight()) {
    car.setY(SCREEN_HEIGHT - car.getHeight());
}
```

In this context, get width and get height are getting the width and height of the image you use for the car, and SCREEN_HEIGHT and SCREEN_WIDTH are constants that hold the width and height of the screen.  You may have to fine tune a bit depending on how your game works.

```
public Class Car {
private int x;
private int y;
private Image image;

public Car(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    image = new Image("location/car.png");
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

Comment: So what would the car class look like... I am fairly new at coding so i dont really understand how to implement it. Should i render it in the GameplayState, or in the Car class itself? Ill post my full GameplayState source in top post.

Comment: I think i know what you mean now... But getX and getY cannot be used for slick Images.

Comment: I edited my comment with an example Car class (My example has no methods, but I assume basic getter/setters).  Basically you create a car object in your init method, and in your update method you set and x and y variables based on the input you are getting.  For example, when you push A you do something like this:  car.rotate(-0.2f * delta) where rotate is a method in the Car class that just calls image.rotate().  You also set x and y the same way when you push W and S.  Then in your render method you should call g.drawImage(car.getImage(), car.getX(), car.getY());  Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know if i am doing something horribly wrong, but i still cant find out how to make a getX or getY / setX and setY method.

Comment: I edited the post with what you need.  Just a basic getter/setter for the ints x and y.  Sorry if I am not explaining clearly :( please let me know if you need something explained better and I shall try my best

Comment: No, you were very good at explaining! I just hvae very little coding experience :). Thought it was something like this, made the getX and getY like that but couldnt figure the setX out. Thanks alot! I'll try it when i get home.

Comment: Ok, tried it now. Made the borders work with a few adjustements, the car can rotate fine, but when you move it acts all weird... Ill attack my new classes up there if you could have a look! thanks!

Comment: Masy, what do you mean by acting weird?  Does it work but not in the way you would expect?  Or does it throw exceptions?

Comment: Also I made an error in the Car class example I made, generally we want our variables to be private, and gain access to them via the getters/setters; I noticed in your border checks you call it via car.x, car.y, that was my fault.  I updated the example to have private variables.

Comment: Also I notice in your getWidth and getHeight Car methods, you are just returning 100.  I believe you can return image.getWidth() and image.getHeight() instead, this way you don't have the values hardcoded in incase you happen to use a bigger/smaller car image down the road.

Comment: CChanged the border checks. Cant change it in the movement part though, it says it has to be a variable, so i kept x and y public. It still acts weird, like you cant drive downwards, only if you hold shift which makes you go faster. It also randmoly drives the wrong ways if you turn in a specific direction. I uploaded a JAR so you can see what i mean: https://mega.co.nz/#!xxRGXDqY!f0ruXijEgAFt-t9KwpnXfRXm50NrcrviQgm0i6mBMo0